# Empty object after `require`

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I'm trying to use your relaxed-json in my Electron app. Here is a simple code, `GetDeviceList()` is triggered on a button-push action:

```
const driver = require('meteor_driver').MeteorConnection.MeteorConnection;
const relaxed = require('relaxed-json');

const connection = new driver();

function GetDeviceList() {

  console.log(connection.port);
  console.log("Launching");
  console.log(relaxed);
  relaxed.transform('[{id:0,},{id:1,},{id:2,},]');
}
```

The console.log show me an empty object. And I got an error message `Uncaught TypeError: relaxed.transform is not a function`.

Otherwise, the package works properly when it's not used with electron.

Note that I don't encounter any `require`-related issue, so the modules must be valid isn't ?

Comment: I've just tested it, it works fine with me, `transform` is defined. Do you use a build system like webpack or something ?

Comment: Did you used this in electron ? This piece of code works well when it's out of Electron.

No i don't use a build system or I'm not aware of this. I know that the module that include `relaxed-json` use `gulp` and `babel`, don't know if this is significent.

Comment: Yes I tested it in electron. I required the module and did a `console.log(relaxed.transform);`, it outputed me `[Function: transform]`

Comment: Ok so this must be an issue with something darker. I also use `electron-rebuild --pre-gyp-fix`. Don't know if this can be helpful to know.

Comment: I didn't know `electron-rebuild`, but this could be the cause, try to use a "vanilla" electron, that might help